# Conditionals in Android Manifest?

Tags: android, ant, android-manifest

Is it at all possible to have conditionals in the Android Manifest? I know that straight out of the box it probably isn't, as this is relied upon by R.java etc. What I'm hoping for is some plugin that'll replace certain parts (comment/uncomment also) of the manifest to simplify  my deployment process.

Basically, we've got some devices that we want to lock down completely, so I set them as `category.HOME` etc. But we also still have some personal devices we still use for testing. As such, it's quite tedious ensuring that I'm not blatting personal devices with a new launcher.

It's petty I know, but in previous languages I'd use `ifdef` etc, but Java doesn't work this way.

I've managed to find this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/eclipsecustomanttasks/ - Which, given some time I could possibly fudge something together, but I must admit, I don't really know where to start, or even if this would be possible?

Was hoping that someone had thought of this before and had a magic solution! :)

Cheers.

Comment: You will need Gradle/Android Studio for this. Look at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a boolean resource -- call it `is_this_for_realz` here -- that is set to `true` for production and `false` otherwise. You can then set up an `<activity-alias>` that has your `HOME` `<intent-filter>`, where that `<activity-alias>` has `android:enabled="@bool/is_this_for_realz"`. Then, whether that `HOME` filter will be used depends upon the state of that boolean resource. You would need to arrange to have your production builds swap in a resource file that sets `is_this_for_realz` to `true`, whereas your normal debug builds would have it be `false`.

As Machinarius notes, this becomes *much* simpler with Gradle for Android. You can go with the boolean resource approach, but have the debug/release variations of `is_this_for_realz` be driven by Gradle build type. Or you can have different manifests for debug and release, if you encounter problems with the `<activity-alias>` technique.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Haven't made the jump to gradle/Android Studio yet. The activity-alias approach will be fine for now. Many thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare - is there a way to have this for permissions. I don't see the android:enabled for <permission/> or <uses-feature/>.

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki: Split your need for conditional elements across build variants (e.g., product flavors). Have custom manifests for each build variant. Have the conditional element that you need in the manifests of the build variants that need them, and leave the off of the stock (`main`) manifest.

Answer (score 5):

Answering a bit late but this is what I did.

First create manifest variables in Gradle as so:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
       
        manifestPlaceholders = [    applicationLabel: "@string/app_name_dev",
                                    azureRedirectURI: "URI_FOR_DEV"]
  
    }

    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [    applicationLabel: "@string/app_name",
                                    azureRedirectURI: "URI_FOR_PROD"]
    }
}
```

And then in the manifest you can do this:

```
<application android:label="${applicationLabel}" />

<activity android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!--Add in your scheme/host from registered redirect URI-->
            <data
                android:scheme="${azureRedirectURI}"
                android:host="auth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Can i use this for booleans?

Comment: Here is a link I saw for that @miguelps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343733/android-manifestplaceholders-how-to-use-a-boolean/49838766