# android manifestPlaceholders - how to use a boolean

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

Manifest placeholder i have created looks like this:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [appDrawerName: "Staging",canExport:"true"]
```

and i am trying to use it to set the following exported property on an activity:

```
<activity android:name=".UI.product.ProductDetailsHostActivity"
           android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme"
           android:exported="${canExport}"/>
```

But i get the following error:

[image]
any ideas on how i can resolve this ? i tried using canExport:true without the quotes but same results.

btw, the first placeholder works fine.

Comment: There is now a bug report for this problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134526664

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to supply a boolean value instead of the string in manifestPlaceholders array.

change this

```
manifestPlaceholders = [appDrawerName: "Staging",canExport:"true"]
```

to

```
manifestPlaceholders = [appDrawerName: "Staging",canExport:true]
```

notice the boolean true instead of string "true"

Comment: For me the version without quotes still results in a "Can not convert string ..." error. And strangely @j2emanue says  " i tried using canExport:true without the quotes but same results.". But he still accepted the answer...?

Comment: its still causing error that answer should not be accepted answer.

Comment: Please check your configuration and usage in AndroidManifest.xml. if it is configured right. it should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
manifestPlaceholders = [               
            extract_native_libs: "true"
    ]

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:extractNativeLibs="${extract_native_libs}"
    android:fullBackupOnly="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

with this config ,android:extractNativeLibs="${extract_native_libs}"  without any lint issue .

meanwhile , it worked as well . so it just might be an IDE issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).